# Change audio advice in SKMaps

Tags: android, skmaps

I am implementing custom turn-by-turn navigation in android using SKMaps. The advice text and images are displayed correctly in the navigation screen.The audio advice only plays the distance and direction (Eg:In 200 feet turn left).But, I want to include the street name(Eg:In 200 feet turn left on XXXX road)in the audio advice.

I have tried to change the audio advice in  "onSignalNewAdviceWithInstruction" method. But, it is not working.

Do I need to change advisor_configfiles settings?

Please provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TTS configuration files already have the street names included. To have the system play TTS generated audio advices see: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec017